# Let $f: R \to R$ fulfill the following $f(x+1)=f(x)$. Prove that for all $n \in Z$ $f(x+n)=f(x)$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, functions, periodic-functions

> Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ fulfill the following $f(x+1)=f(x)$.
>
> 1.) Prove that for all $n \in Z$ $f(x+n)=f(x)$.
>
> 2.) Prove that if the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=L$ exists, then f is a constant.

1.) Since we're given that $n \in Z$, I was immediately drawn to using induction. f is a periodic function with a period of 1.

Let's try n=1:

$f(x+1)=f(x)$

This is correct because that's what was given. Let's assume for any $n\in N$ this statement still holds true. Let's try for $n+1$:

$f(x+(n+1)$

Since we assumed n is true we can set (n+1)=m, and $m\in N$,therefore

$f(x+m)=f(x)$

Is my work correct? By induction we assume it holds true for n, adding 1 is just adding another period to the function.

2.) I'm having difficulties even starting with this one. Was thinking about using derivatives but it's not explicitly  given that f is differentiable.

Comment: For question #1, what about non-positive $n$?

Comment: @KennyLau you're right. I'm so used to seeing n \in N that I overlooked an entire group of numbers/didn't read the question correctly.

Comment: For question #2, if $f$ is not a constant, then it oscillates and does not have a limit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your proof is good for proving that $f(x+n)=f(x)$ for *positive* integers $m$.

However, if you notice that
$$
f(x-1)=f((x-1)+1)=f(x)
$$
you'll be able to complete the proof for negative integers as well.

For the second part, assume $f$ is not constant, so there are $x_1$ and $x_2$ with $f(x_1)\ne f(x_2)$. Consider the sequences
$$
a_n=x_1+n,\qquad b_n=x_2+n
$$
What can you say about
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f(b_n)
$$
taking into account that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$?

If you can't use sequences, it's a bit more complicated. But you can notice that, given $M>0$, there always is $n$ such that $x_1+n>M$ and $x_2+n>M$.

Take $\varepsilon=|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|/2$ and try seeing what happens taking into account that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$.

Comment: Ahh we weren't taught sequences/series in this course besides Taylor so won't be able to use that method, but thanks for helping me complete #1.

Comment: @RonaldB No problem: you can use them in disguise to make an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof.

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is $1-$periodic. Therefore, if $f$ is not constant, there is $x, y$ s.t. $f(x)\neq f(y)$. In particular, $$f(x)=f(x+n)\neq f(y+n)=f(y)$$
for all $n$. By taking $n\to \infty $, you get that $$\lim_{n\to \infty }f(x+n)=f(x)\neq f(y)=\lim_{n\to \infty }f(y+n)$$
and thus $\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x)$ doesn't exist, which is a contradiction.

Comment: $f(x)=\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x+n)$ must be $f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty }f(x+n)$

Comment: This is not true. For instance, $1/n \neq 0$ for all $n$, although $\lim (1/n) = 0$.

Comment: @AhmedHussein: This proof is correct. I construct two sequence $(a_n=x+n)_n$ and $(b_n=y+n)_n$ that diverge to $+\infty $ and s.t. $\lim_{n\to \infty }f(a_n)\neq \lim_{n\to \infty }f(b_n)$

Comment: @Surb sorry, the way it was written at first seemed to imply otherwise.